# Merge connected lines and split them after set unequal distances

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, merge, dissolve, splitting

I need to edit line features in QGIS 3.4.4. I have more than 1000 line features that I want to first merge and then split. The line features describe roads in useless intervals, my goal is to highlight specific parts of the roads after set intervals.

I want to do the following:

- Merge connecting lines into a single feature of the whole road. If there is no easy solution I might have to select and merge them by hand.
- Split the lines up into parts after set distances, e.g. first after 5 kilometers, next after 1.2 kilometers etc.

I already tried the v.split script, but I only manage to split the line into equal parts. The best solution for splitting would look something like this in ArcGIS:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDQQtn1l4cQ

I only work in QGIS however.

Comment: What is a your definition of connected lines? Are lines that intersect "connected"? Do you want to join segments between intersections?

Comment: @user3386170 I uploaded this picture that might help me clarify:
https://ibb.co/SK6J0HD
As you can see, I selected a part of the road. I want to connect the whole road on the right side into one feature and the whole road on the left side into another.

Comment: The right side of what? Did you try `Dissolve` and then `Multipart to singleparts` (available in processing toolbox)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the image on this page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following things :

1. Dissolve the layer with the continue line. Use the tool `dissolve`.
2. Create points along the line  with the tool `Points along geometry`[image]

3. Use the SAGA tool `Split line at points`.

Comment: Thank you for the help! However, the line shouldn't be split up at at regular interval but rather into several pieces with different lenghts.

Comment: In that case, this link should be usefull : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232016/how-to-place-points-along-a-line-using-a-list-of-distances-in-qgis

Comment: That link provides instructions for placing points at specified distances along a line. Once you have the points you can use the `split lines at points` algorithm to split the lines.